# Extracting Feature from an Image - suggestions for best approach?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I am currently learning computer vision and I would like to extract the onion from the image. What would be the best approach to do this?

I attempted a thresholding approach to detect white colour by breaking down the image into its R,G,B channels, but that also detects light reflections on other parts of the image. How could I clean up this image to obtain a mask that approximately represents the onion?

```
onionRGB = imread('onion.png');
onionGRAY = rgb2gray(onionRGB);

figure, imshow(onionRGB);

% split channels
rOnion = onionRGB(:, :, 1);             % red channel
gOnion = onionRGB(:, :, 2);             % green channel
bOnion = onionRGB(:, :, 3);             % blue channel


whiteThresh = 160*3;
% detect white onion
onionDetection = double(rOnion) + double(gOnion) + double(bOnion);

% apply thresholding to segment the foreground
maskOnion = onionDetection > whiteThresh;
figure, imshow(maskOnion);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code, placed after splitting into channels, works well.

```
onionHSV = rgb2hsv(onionRGB);
saturationOnion = onionHSV(:,:,2);
figure;
imagesc(saturationOnion);
title('Saturation');

figure;
imagesc(rOnion+bOnion); title('purple');

%apply threshold to saturation and purple brightness levels
maskOnion = and((saturationOnion < 0.645), (rOnion+bOnion >=155));
%filter out all but the largest object
maskOnion = bwareafilt(maskOnion,1);
figure, imshow(maskOnion);
```

The first trick is using saturation from the HSV representation of the colors for filtering purposes.
The second trick is thresholding on more than one channel.
The third trick is filtering out all but the largest object.

[image: the onion mask]